# Vue: computed vs data(), for vuex bindings?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

(Note: I not am not asking about how to use `watch`).

I have this form template and want to bind it to some variables, for example `objectvalue3`, that are tracked in a Vuex store (note: different forms may be present on one page, so `props.formname` tells the form where to look).

```
<template>
    <div>
    Tracking formname_:{{formname_}}:
        <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="objectvalue3" :value="objectvalue3" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" value="Track" @click.prevent="write">        
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
....
props: {
    formname: {
        type: String,
        default: "main"
    }
},
```

Tracking it in `data` does **not** work - i.e. the form does not get updated - it just keeps the value the vuex was initialized to :

```
data: function() {
    return {
        formname_: this.formname
        ,objectvalue3: this.$store.state.tracker[this.formname].objectvalue3
},
```

But using `computed` works.

```
computed: {
    objectvalue3: function() {
        return this.$store.state.tracker[this.formname].objectvalue3
    }
```

I know I have to use `computed` when I need to do calculations.  But there is not real calculation going on here.  Unless, could it be the hash lookup via `this.formname` which tells the form which `tracker` attribute to look at that is causing a straight `data` to fail?  Is this specific to vuex?

Comment: I am not using a watch though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        formname_: this.formname,
        tracker: this.$store.state.tracker[this.formname]
},
```

Then:

```
<input type="text" name="objectvalue3" :value="tracker.objectvalue3" />
```

This should work because the data's `tracker` object is pointing to the one in the store, then whenever the value changes there, it'll also change in the `tracker` object.

`computed` works because it listens to changes in the variables used within it, while data doesn't because it applies the first value when executed and doesn't track changes.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if I am using the right semantics, but, if I understood you correctly data can hold a reference to an object and then knows what's going on on its attributes?  However, when it is used to look at an immutable attribute, like an int or a string, then it copies by value and does not track further changes?  Subtle effects around references and immutable variables often bite people in the Python world, so these are the terms I am using, perhaps incorrectly for JS.

Comment: Yeah, this is a javascript thing. If you do `var yourVar = Number/String`, instead of copying the reference, the value is passed instead. But if you do `var yourVar = Object` then you're passing the reference to the object, and not copying it.

Comment: I have marked your question as duplicate because the answer in that question might help you.

Comment: aha, just like Python ;-)

Comment: `State` should not be referenced in your component. You can use a `getter` instead or 
 `mapGetters` as a shorthand.

Comment: @AndréRavazzi that's correct. My answer is correct as in changing the template data, but it's not the proper Vuex usage.